# Germanium transistor in high voltage

Tags: high-voltage

I want to make one of those circuits 
using an old PNP germanium transistor (2SB175)
what values of resistors should I chose and which circuit is good ? , if the circuits are bad, is there any better arc generator (hv) circuit using this transistor (2SB175) ?

Could anyone please help me.
Thanks

[image: high voltage circuit 1]
[image: high voltage circuit 2]

[image: 2SB175 PNP transistor]

Comment: Have you compared the specifications for a 2N3055 with your 2SB175? They are completely different animals.

Comment: lol , yes I compared them but i want a mini thing

Comment: What is a "mini thing"? Don't you have a big transformer as well?

Comment: I mean a small device easy circuit , 2n3055 need big heatsync , no I want to use aa batteries

Comment: You say you have a PNP transistor, but all your schematics show NPN. You should include a schematic of the circuit you are actually proposing to build (use the embedded schematic editor when editing your question).

Comment: I dont know how to replace npn transistor , and I dont know how to calcule resistor values , I want a working schematic for pnp transistor , I think I have to replace the npn with a pnp and flip battery poles ?

Comment: Is it for plasma generation ( i mean plasma tube or globe) or Arc generation?

Comment: All are the same , what I want is hv arc on output

Answer (score 1):

the transistor of 2sb175 is poor transistor it is a signal transistor vce=30v, ic=100mA

But the 2n3055 is a power transistor: vce=60v, ic=15A and it support a high current to diver a good current to supply the primary of step up transformer to generate a high voltge at the secondery coil

from this point you can't replace 2n3055 by 2sb175

if you want to make this circuit just buy a 2N3055

if you want to make this circuit with PNP power transistor just invert the power supply

Answer (score 1):

Those old germanium transistors are very intolerant of abuse (ask me how I know). Note the abs maximum junction temperature of only 85°C and maximum power dissipation of 125mW at Ta = 25°C (meaning that it's really only good for a few tens of mW).

They're not really suited for experimentation with unknown flyback transformers, the most likely outcome is that you'll fry the transistor before you learn anything.

It is not impossible to make some kind of very low current high voltage generator with that transistor, but it would involve some effort and knowledge, and you're never going to see big awe-inspiring arcs (or even much in the way of little sparks) coming from that transformer secondary.